# how to run a MDX query direcly via saiku

Tags: java, olap, pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I have a code which runs direct MDX query using the execute function. But the [documentation](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/api/mondrian/olap/Connection.html#execute%28mondrian.olap.Query%29) says this function is deprecated.

```
RolapConnection rcon = olapConnection.unwrap(RolapConnection.class);
String mdx = "select NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[c], [Measures].[I]})} ON COLUMNS,  NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({{[Time].[2013].[May2013], [Time].[2013].[Jun2013]}})} ON ROWS from [Metrics]";
Query q = rcon.parseQuery(mdx);
Result result = rcon.execute(query);
```

What is the alternative to this function ? How to achieve this in new version of mondrian ?

Answer (score 2):

i am not aware with what you are trying but i can suggest you alternative for achieving the same.

Try pentaho schame workbench for writing MDX query and publish it into pentaho bi server, their is a plugin for siaku in BI Server so that you can run your mdx query in Saiku as well.